# Read specific number of bytes which is in acceptable data

Tags: go, networking, tcp

I have a binary package of data, but length of the package is a first 4 bytes of it. Is there a correct way to read length and then read whole package with net.Conn in GoLang?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is `b:=make([]byte,4); con.Read(b)` too obvious?

Comment: `io.ReadFull()` should be preferred, `con.Read()` does not guarantee that the full slice will be populated. Also `binary.LittleEndian.Uint32()` if you don't want to shuffle bytes manually.

Comment: Why don't use `binary.Read` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "io"
)

```
func ReadPacket(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error) {
    lenB := make([]byte, 4)

    if _, err := r.Read(lenB); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    //you can use BigEndian depending on the proto
    l := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(lenB)

    packet := make([]byte, l)

    _, err := r.Read(packet)

    return packet, err
}
```